# Can't check if time is over using NOW

Tags: ico, timestamp, modifiers

I'm coding a smart contract for an ICO and I have a problem. I have a modifier wich checks if NOW > timestamp,
but it's not working for some reason. Here is the function:

```
function DeleteModerator(uint _ModeratorId, address _ModeratorAddress) onlyOwner checkICOtime public
{
        delete moderators[_ModeratorAddress];
        delete Moderators[_ModeratorId];
}
```

and the modifier:

```
modifier checkICOtime()
{
     require(now > 1515868200);
     _;
}
```

When im trying to send this function using Mist it's keep saying: "We couldn't estimate the gas" and "this transaction will fail". I have no idead what is the problem here. It's very simple thing, but im stack. Please help.